# WPF using LocalDB doesn't deploy correctly

Tags: deployment, clickonce, localdb

I've written a program that uses Code First with LocalDB to store data. After using Click Once to deploy, the application doesn't create the LocalDB in production. I've tried all of the Database Initializers, and the app just errors out saying that no tables actually exist.

I'm assuming that there is something simple that I'm missing, but all the articles I find seem to refer to using SQL Express.

**Edit**

May be related to EF 6.1.1. I've tried downgrading to 5 and it appears to be working, but I'm not done testing yet.

Comment: Have you tried running it explicitly as an Administrator and have you checked the windows application log. Also, are you swallowing any exceptions?

Comment: You are aware that LocalDB is meant for running under user, not as a service, right? Are you creating the instance (using sqllocaldb.exe) or using the default (localdb)\v11.0?

Comment: @Silvermind It's a Click Once deploy, so I can't figure out how to run it as Administrator.

Comment: @DannyVarod Yes, I want it run under user. I'm using the default (localdb)\v11.0 in the connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading EF from 6.1.1 to 5.0.0 has resolved this issue. I can only assume that this is a bug in 6.1.1.